# Getting only the entity IDs in a Criteria query

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria

I have to write a method such as public `List<Integer> findIds(String someVendor)` that gets only the IDs of entities matching a given property value (example, vendor).

Given this example

```
public class Product{
    private int id;

    private String vendor;
}
```

I can easily write the restriction criteria to match the vendor.

But I don't know how `Criteria.list()` may return `Integer`

```
return session.createCriteria(Producrt.class)
.add(Restrictions.eq("vendor",someVendor)
//What here?
.list();
```

Also, if I was using C#/LINQ, I would have written the following

```
return (from products product where product.vendor == someVendor select id).ToList();
```

I have never used projections in Hibernate/Java. How do I return only the IDs of matching entities into a list?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try below code,

```
sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Product.class).add(
            Restrictions.eq("vendor", "vendor-value")).setProjection(Projections.property("id"))
```

Comment: AFAIK it's supposed to return List<Product>. I'm going to debug that in half an hour

Comment: No, that worked. I've successfully obtained a List<Integer> from that query!!